# neo4j graphaware php-client: connection refused

Tags: php, neo4j, graphaware

I run an XAMPP locally on a MacBook. On the same machine I run neo4j Enterprise. The database is version 3.5.6.

When I try to connect to the database via the php client I get a warning ans a fatal error:

> Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://localhost:7687 (Connection refused) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-bolt/src/IO/StreamSocket.php on line 203
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught GraphAware\Bolt\Exception\IOException: Error to connect to the server(111) : "Connection refused" in /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-bolt/src/IO/StreamSocket.php:207 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-bolt/src/IO/StreamSocket.php(245): GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket->connect() #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-bolt/src/Driver.php(133): GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket->reconnect() #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-bolt/src/Driver.php(115): GraphAware\Bolt\Driver->handshake() #3 /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/src/Connection/Connection.php(192): GraphAware\Bolt\Driver->session() #4 /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/src/Connection/Connection.php(109): GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection->checkSession() #5 /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-client/src/Client.php(220): Gra in /opt/lampp/htdocs/avi-law_codetest/vendor/graphaware/neo4j-bolt/src/IO/StreamSocket.php on line 207

The same story goes for `https` and bolt (just with the other two ports in the error statement).

I have checked the `Username` (neo4j) and the `password` (Neo1234) via the Browser interface to the database. Both are correct. I have also tried to replace "localhost" by the IP-address of the Apache-server.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\ClientBuilder;

$client = ClientBuilder::create()
//->addConnection("default", "http://neo4j:Neo1234@localhost:7474")
->addConnection('bolt', 'bolt://neo4j:Neo1234@localhost:7687')
->build();

$query = 'MATCH (user:User {name:"john"})
CREATE (friend:User {name:"Judith"})
MERGE (user)-[r:FRIEND]->(friend)
RETURN user, friend, r';

$result = $client->sendCypherQuery($query)->getResult();

$john = $result->get('user');
$judith = $result->get('judith');

// What john has for relationships

print_r($john->getRelationships()); // returns relationships objects
```

If did a var_dump() on the $client variable which results as follows:

> object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Client)#23 (2) { ["connectionManager":protected]=> object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager)#2 (2) { ["connections":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager":private]=> array(1) { ["bolt"]=> object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection)#4 (5) { ["alias":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=> string(4) "bolt" ["uri":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=> string(35) "bolt://neo4j:Neo1234@localhost:7687" ["driver":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=> object(GraphAware\Bolt\Driver)#18 (6) { ["io":protected]=> object(GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket)#21 (9) { ["protocol":protected]=> string(3) "tcp" ["host":protected]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port":protected]=> int(7687) ["context":protected]=> resource(64) of type (stream-context) ["keepAlive":protected]=> bool(false) ["eventDispatcher":protected]=> object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#20 (3) { ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["optimized":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } } ["timeout":protected]=> int(5) ["sock":"GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket":private]=> NULL ["configuration":"GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket":private]=> object(GraphAware\Bolt\Configuration)#19 (7) { ["credentials":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "neo4j" [1]=> string(7) "Neo1234" } ["username":protected]=> string(5) "neo4j" ["password":protected]=> string(7) "Neo1234" ["bindtoInterface":protected]=> NULL ["timeout":protected]=> NULL ["tlsMode":protected]=> NULL ["data":"GraphAware\Common\Connection\BaseConfiguration":private]=> array(6) { ["user"]=> string(4) "null" ["password"]=> string(7) "Neo1234" ["bind_to_interface"]=> string(4) "null" ["timeout"]=> int(5) ["credentials"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "neo4j" [1]=> string(7) "Neo1234" } ["username"]=> string(5) "neo4j" } } } ["dispatcher":protected]=> object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#20 (3) { ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["optimized":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } } ["sessionRegistry":protected]=> object(GraphAware\Bolt\Protocol\SessionRegistry)#22 (3) { ["io":protected]=> object(GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket)#21 (9) { ["protocol":protected]=> string(3) "tcp" ["host":protected]=> string(9) "localhost" ["port":protected]=> int(7687) ["context":protected]=> resource(64) of type (stream-context) ["keepAlive":protected]=> bool(false) ["eventDispatcher":protected]=> object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#20 (3) { ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["optimized":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } } ["timeout":protected]=> int(5) ["sock":"GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket":private]=> NULL ["configuration":"GraphAware\Bolt\IO\StreamSocket":private]=> object(GraphAware\Bolt\Configuration)#19 (7) { ["credentials":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "neo4j" [1]=> string(7) "Neo1234" } ["username":protected]=> string(5) "neo4j" ["password":protected]=> string(7) "Neo1234" ["bindtoInterface":protected]=> NULL ["timeout":protected]=> NULL ["tlsMode":protected]=> NULL ["data":"GraphAware\Common\Connection\BaseConfiguration":private]=> array(6) { ["user"]=> string(4) "null" ["password"]=> string(7) "Neo1234" ["bind_to_interface"]=> string(4) "null" ["timeout"]=> int(5) ["credentials"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "neo4j" [1]=> string(7) "Neo1234" } ["username"]=> string(5) "neo4j" } } } ["dispatcher":protected]=> object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#20 (3) { ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["optimized":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } } ["sessions":protected]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(35) "GraphAware\Bolt\Protocol\V1\Session" } } ["versionAgreed":protected]=> bool(false) ["session":protected]=> NULL ["credentials":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "neo4j" [1]=> string(7) "Neo1234" } } ["config":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=> object(GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\HttpDriver\Configuration)#17 (3) { ["timeout":protected]=> NULL ["curlInterface":protected]=> NULL ["data":"GraphAware\Common\Connection\BaseConfiguration":private]=> array(3) { ["http_client"]=> object(Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client)#5 (1) { ["client":"Http\Adapter\Guzzle6\Client":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Client)#15 (1) { ["config":"GuzzleHttp\Client":private]=> array(7) { ["handler"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack)#6 (3) { ["handler":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> object(Closure)#13 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["default"]=> object(Closure)#11 (2) { ["static"]=> array(2) { ["default"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler)#7 (5) { ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#8 (2) { ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> array(0) { } ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> int(50) } ["selectTimeout":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> int(1) ["active":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> NULL ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } ["delays":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlMultiHandler":private]=> array(0) { } } ["sync"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler)#9 (1) { ["factory":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler":private]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)#10 (2) { ["handles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> array(0) { } ["maxHandles":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory":private]=> int(3) } } } ["parameter"]=> array(2) { ["$request"]=> string(10) "" ["$options"]=> string(10) "" } } ["streaming"]=> object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler)#12 (1) { ["lastHeaders":"GuzzleHttp\Handler\StreamHandler":private]=> array(0) { } } } ["parameter"]=> array(2) { ["$request"]=> string(10) "" ["$options"]=> string(10) "" } } ["stack":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(Closure)#14 (1) { ["parameter"]=> array(1) { ["$handler"]=> string(10) "" } } [1]=> string(12) "prepare_body" } } ["cached":"GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack":private]=> NULL } ["allow_redirects"]=> array(5) { ["max"]=> int(5) ["protocols"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "http" [1]=> string(5) "https" } ["strict"]=> bool(false) ["referer"]=> bool(false) ["track_redirects"]=> bool(false) } ["http_errors"]=> bool(true) ["decode_content"]=> bool(true) ["verify"]=> bool(true) ["cookies"]=> bool(false) ["headers"]=> array(1) { ["User-Agent"]=> string(39) "GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.53.1 PHP/7.3.10" } } } } ["request_factory"]=> object(Http\Message\MessageFactory\GuzzleMessageFactory)#16 (0) { } ["timeout"]=> int(5) } } ["session":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\Connection":private]=> NULL } } ["master":"GraphAware\Neo4j\Client\Connection\ConnectionManager":private]=> NULL } ["eventDispatcher":protected]=> object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher)#24 (3) { ["listeners":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["sorted":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } ["optimized":"Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher":private]=> array(0) { } } }

The settings in the neo4j.conf are in the default status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. It was the (bad) relationship between XAMPP Apache and onboard Mac OS Apache. They somehow interfere when you try to access "http://localhost". I have stopped the XAMPP Apache, followed the steps given [here](https://websitebeaver.com/set-up-localhost-on-macos-high-sierra-apache-mysql-and-php-7-with-sslhttps) and voilà, the problem was gone.